# Python - finding specific string in files

Tags: python, regex, readfile

I try to read specific string in files. Basically file look like this:

```
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|1|48|89|36|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|2|43|83|108|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|3|37|85|180|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|4|37|93|252|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|5|43|95|324|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|6|42|89|36|Single|

[META DATA]
01/10/2015|14:50:27|USA|UWI_N2C34_2|MMS1|FORD35|Bednarek|true|6|0|false|

[QUALITY CAMERA CHECK]
1|1|0|
2|1|0|
3|1|0|
4|1|0|
5|1|0|
6|1|0|

[PRESET]
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|TA|
```

What I need is to read from line: `01/10/2015|14:50:27|USA|UWI_N2C34_2|MMS1|FORD35|Bednarek|true|6|0|false|` 
a country name between string `|USA|`

To do that I tried to use function group which is part of regular expression. I deduced that I need to read from specific line which hold this string. So I wrote small code:

```
import os
import string
import re
import sys
import glob
import fileinput

country_pattern = 'MYS','IDN','ZAF', 'THA','TWN','SGP', 'NWZ', 'AUS','ALB','AUT','BEL', 'BGR', 'BIH', 'CHE','CZE', 'DEU', 'DNK', 'ESP','EST','SRB','MDK','MNE','BIH', 'BIH','MNE','FIN', 'FRA', 'GBR','GRC', 'HRV', 'HUN', 'IRL', 'ITA', 'LIE', 'LTU', 'LUX', 'LVA', 'MDA', 'SMR','CYP','NLD','NOR','POL','PRT','ROU','SCG', 'SVK','SVN','SWE','TUR','BRA','CAN','USA','MEX','CHL','ARG','RUS'
pattern = r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)|(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)|(\S+)|(\S+)|(\S+)|(\S+)|(\S+)|(\S+)|(\d+)|(\d+)|(\S+)|'

src = raw_input("Enter source disk location: ")
src = os.path.dirname(src) 
for dir,_,_ in os.walk(src): 
    file_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.txt")) 
    for file in file_path:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    object_name = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    for line_name_tmp in object_name:
        line_name = line_name_tmp.replace('\n','')
        if line_name == '':
            line_name.split()
            continue
        else:
            try:
                searchObj = re.search(pattern, line_name)
                m = searchObj.group(7)
                if m in country_pattern:
                    print "searchObj.group(7) : ", searchObj.group(7)
                else:
                    print 'did not find any match'
            except:
                print line_name
                pass
```

But it will always print me  'did not find any match'. Did I miss something ?
Thanks for advise.

Comment: personally, I'd read each line in the file until I found `[META DATA]`, then the following line. I'd then split it `ls=line.split('|')` and take its third element with `country=ls[2]`

Comment: great solution , thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your re is the problem
try this one

```
pattern = r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\|(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\d+)\|(\d+)\|(\S+)\|'
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i was missing :)

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions, the character `|` separates alternatives. So if you define a regex like this,

```
(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)|(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)
```

it will match a string of the form `digits/digits/digits` **or** a string of the form `digits:digits:digits`. Not both.

Accordingly, when you take your `pattern` regex and search the line

```
01/10/2015|14:50:27|USA|UWI_N2C34_2|MMS1|FORD35|Bednarek|true|6|0|false|
```

for a match, the regex winds up matching only the part `01/10/2015`, because that part is matched by the first alternative (`(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)`). The seventh capturing group in the regex is not within the part that matched, so `m.group(7)` returns `None`, and of course `None` is not one of the elements in `country_pattern`.

The easy - or one might say lazy - way to fix this is to escape the pipe characters in the definition of the regex: use `\|` instead of `|`. But since you have fields separated by `|` in the file, I think you might have a better designed program if you were to use `line_name.split('|')` and then pick out the third field, instead of using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
if need just to find it text country abbreviation this will do it:

data = '''
01/10/2015|14:50:27|USA|UWI_N2C34_2|MMS1|FORD35|Bednarek|true|6|0|false|
'''
country_pattern = 'MYS','IDN','ZAF', 'THA','TWN','SGP', 'NWZ', 'AUS','ALB','AUT','BEL', 'BGR', 'BIH', 'CHE','CZE', 'DEU', 'DNK', 'ESP','EST','SRB','MDK','MNE','BIH', 'BIH','MNE','FIN', 'FRA', 'GBR','GRC', 'HRV', 'HUN', 'IRL', 'ITA', 'LIE', 'LTU', 'LUX', 'LVA', 'MDA', 'SMR','CYP','NLD','NOR','POL','PRT','ROU','SCG', 'SVK','SVN','SWE','TUR','BRA','CAN','USA','MEX','CHL','ARG','RUS'

mo = re.search(r'\|[A-Z]{3}\|',data)
if mo:
    print(mo.group(0))


|USA|
```